# How to solve $x a^x + b^x = c$?

Tags: exponential-function

I need to solve this equation for $x$:  $x a^x + b^x = c$ where $a, b, c$ are real numbers. Does it have closed form solution?

Comment: no.....................................

Comment: See Wikipedia's ["Transcendental equation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) entry.

Comment: Numerical methods only could do the job.

Comment: what if it is like $a 2^x - x = c$?

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you asked for $a \,2^x - x = c$.

So, consider that you look for the zero(s) of function
$$f(x)=a \,2^x - x - c$$
$$f'(x)=a\, 2^x \log (2)-1$$
$$f''(x)=a \,2^x \log ^2(2)$$

The first derivative cancels at $x_*$
$$x_*=-\frac{\log (a \log (2))+1}{\log (2)}$$ which only exist if $a >0$. At this point
$$f(x_*)=\frac{\log \left({a \log (2)}\right)}{\log (2)}+\frac{1}{\log (2)}-c$$
$$f''(x_*)=\log (2) > 0$$
If $f(x_*) <0$, then there are two roots which will be given interms of Lambert function
$$x_1=-\frac{W_0\left(-a\, 2^{-c} \log (2)\right)}{\log (2)}-c\qquad \text{and} \qquad x_2=-\frac{W_{-1}\left(-a\, 2^{-c} \log (2)\right)}{\log (2)}-c $$

Comment: OP posted that equation as a [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2840346/409).