# How to solve $a 2^x - x = b$?

Tags: exponential-function

I need to solve $a 2^x - x = b$ for $x$ where $a$ and $b$ are parameters. Does it have closed form solution? I need to substitute $x$ in another system of equations in Mathematica.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 3):

$$x = -{\frac {{\rm W} \left(-\ln  \left( 2 \right) a{2}^{-b}\right)}{\ln 
 \left( 2 \right) }}-b$$
where $\rm W$ is any branch of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (**ProductLog** in Mathematica).

But if you have Mathematica, why didn't you ask Mathematica to solve it?

Comment: I answered  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840231/how-to-solve-x-ax-bx-c/2840373#2840373